# Can water get in to the transmission vents and differential, while going off-road into a swamp?

Tags: honda

Can a Cr-V 2.0 i4 iVTec sport variant, get water in to the transmission vents and differential, while going off-road into a swamp 8 inch deep and 500 foot long?

*Diving speed is around 40 MPH, exit speed is between 20 to 25 MPH.

Comment: Usually I maintain 5500 RPM, but while exiting the RPM dropped to 1000 on the gauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8" depth of water is not enough water to get into the transmission or differential, if you are not moving. If you are moving, 8" of water could allow water to enter the vents, depending on how much the water gets splashed around. Hard to say. When in doubt, check it out! Change the fluid. Pull the drain plug after the vehicle sits for a while. The water should separate and drop to the bottom.  If water comes out, drain all the fluid out, refill with the correct fluid, driver a several miles then change it again, right after driving, and refill with the correct fluid to the proper level.

Comment: Nothing. There is no indication of water mixture on the dipstick.

Comment: The drain plug refers to transmission or diff so most likely not to have a dipstick - most transmission / diffs have a filler hole to indicate the level...

Comment: Differential usually gets a bit of water from the breather hose. I can't think of re-routing it elsewhere. Meanwhile I can't comprehend why the RPM drops to 1000 from 5500 and speed as well? From 70 MPH it can be down to 40 MPH?

Comment: Upon inspection no mixture was noticed in the tranny or the diff. Yet, Honda techs replaced both. I added water to the old oil in the catching tub, surprisingly it didn't change color or texture. Very difficult to judge. Anyway it's in the past until I water Dive again.

Answer (score 1):

There's going to be a huge amount of splashing.  I suggest if this is a regular thing that you plumb "snorkels" with lengths of hose to relocate the vent points much higher on the vehicle.

You really hit an 8 inch deep "swamp" at 40 mph??  Braver man than I.

Comment: How high should I take them? I checked the fluid on the dipstick, nothing seems to be there. No mixture.

Comment: I've hit partial water bodies at 70 MPH as well. But the wheel that goes in pulls hard in to the water. Very scary initially. God willing, I'm still alive. This is not bravery, it's called suicide if something goes wrong. Please don't attempt at higher speed just using my case as an example. I do this every time it rains heavily.

Comment: Show me some pictures, I don't even know where they are. I just understand the theory.

Comment: I can't say how high *you* need.  But the best places for this specific advice would be a google search on the offroad vehicles set up for fording 4 or 5 or more feet of water.  There are probably even generic kits to do this.  Your problem might be maintaining *aesthetics* - You obviously don't want to drill vent holes for tubing in your roof.  Folks that have an FJ40 aren't interested in pretty.

Comment: On landrovers we used to move the axle breathers as the cooling on a warm axle would "pull" water in past the seals ...

Comment: Mind you, live to see a video of the op doing this at 40mph - the braking effect !!!

Comment: I'm not shooting any videos. I need full visibility, anything on the windshield is a hindrance. This is on public roads, too many factors to account for.